# Jquery pass wrong value to page

Tags: php, jquery

I have been struggling with this for days. This works, but does not pass the correct variable to the page ( testMap.php ). I use data from my DB and hovering over the link does show the correct variables in the URL, but for whatever reason jquery is always grabbing the first variable in the loop. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
    $myname = $_SESSION['username'];
    global $database;
    $stmt = $database->connection->query("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_FLIGHTS." WHERE username='$myname'");

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $date       = $row['date'];
                    $starting   = $row['starting'];
                    $ending     = $row['ending'];
                    $route      = $row['route'];
                  echo "<a class=\"route\" href=\"start=$starting&end=$ending\"><p class=\"pBlue\">$date - $starting - $ending - $route</p></a>";
                  ?>
        <div id="start" style="visibility:hidden"><?php echo $starting; ?></div>
        <div id="end" style="visibility:hidden"><?php echo $ending; ?></div>
        <?
    }

    ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var start = $('#start').text();
    var end = $('#end').text();

    $(function() {
      $(".route").click(function(evt) {
         $("#mymap_canvas").load("testMap.php?start="+start+"&end="+end )
         evt.preventDefault();
      })
    })

});
</script>
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique. That loop tells me that you're creating multiple elements with ID start and end, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed; you need to capture the start and end values within the click event and choose the start and end values that are nearby to the route that was clicked.

Possibly what you want:

```
$(".route").click(function(evt) {
    var start = $(this).siblings(".start").text();
    var end = $(this).siblings(".end").text();
    $("#mymap_canvas").load("testMap.php?start="+start+"&end="+end )
    evt.preventDefault();
}); // I believe you are missing a semicolon here and at the end, too
```

But unless I'm missing something you could really just build that href via php (like you already are except complete it with the full path and query string) and then execute it like this:

```
$(".route").click(function(evt) {
    // Load the href of the route anchor into 'mymap_canvas'
    $("#mymap_canvas").load($(this).attr("href"));
    event.preventDefault();
    return false; // Prevent the normal click behavior
});
```

No more hidden start and end! But be sure to update your original anchor tag to look like this:

```
<a class=\"route\" href=\"testMap.php?start={$starting}&end={$ending}\">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $myname = $_SESSION['username'];
    global $database;
    $stmt = $database->connection->query("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_FLIGHTS." WHERE username='$myname'");
$i=1;
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $date       = $row['date'];
                    $starting   = $row['starting'];
                    $ending     = $row['ending'];
                    $route      = $row['route'];
                  echo "<a class=\"route\" href=\"start=$starting&end=$ending\"><p class=\"pBlue\">$date - $starting - $ending - $route</p></a>";
                  ?>
        <div class="start<?php echo $i; ?>" style="visibility:hidden"><?php echo $starting; ?></div>
        <div class="end<?php echo $i ?>" style="visibility:hidden"><?php echo $ending; ?></div>
        <?
   $i++; }

    ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var start = $('.start1').text();
    var end = $('.end<?php echo $i; ?>').text();

    $(function() {
      $(".route").click(function(evt) {
         $("#mymap_canvas").load("testMap.php?start="+start+"&end="+end )
         evt.preventDefault();
      })
    })

});
</script>
```

Comment: That gives the variable $starting all values: $starting = khiiklaskord Starting should equal just khii   for example. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: what you exact want please brief little more

Comment: i need $starting to show the results from that query, and $ending to show the results as well. Whats happening is, jquery is only passing the first result from the database query.

Comment: @MohitBumb; I don't think that's what should be done; the $i is changing up in the php for loop which does not surround the jQuery portion at the bottom. $i in the `(document).ready()` is just going to be the last element instead of the first one.

Comment: okay in start i write start1 so it returns first value and in end i write $i so it returns where loop ends value :p